# HTMLCanvasElement Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, mshtml, type-mismatch

I'm using VBA to script an InternetExplorer instance with a Canvas on it. I have it set up so I can use classes in VBA like Circle and Line to draw on the canvas.  This is all working fine and I have a force directed animated graph working.

However, now I'm trying to capture user events such as mouse clicks as events in VBA and I'm encountering a strange issue. **I create a variable of type HTMLCanvasElement, but when I try to assign the HTMLCanvasElement object to it, I get a Type Mismatch error.**

NOTE: You need to add references to "Microsoft Internet Controls" for the `InternetExplorer` class object and "Microsoft HTML Object Library" for the MSHTML class objects.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim document As HTMLDocument
Dim WithEvents window As HTMLWindow2
Dim ctx As ICanvasRenderingContext2D
Dim WithEvents canvas As MSHTML.HTMLCanvasElement

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.StatusBar = False
    ie.AddressBar = False
    ie.MenuBar = False
    ie.Toolbar = False

    ie.Navigate "about:blank"
    While Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ie.Visible = True
    Set document = ie.document
    document.body.innerHTML = "<div><canvas id='myCanvas' width='10' height='10' style=""border:1px solid #000000;"">" & _
            "Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag" & _
            "</canvas></div>"

    'Set canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")  'This line triggers a Type Mismatch!!!

    Set ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d")

    Set window = document.parentWindow

    resizeCanvas
End Sub

Private Sub window_onload()
    window_onresize
End Sub

Private Sub window_onresize()
    resizeCanvas
End Sub

Public Sub resizeCanvas()
    ctx.canvas.Width = window.innerWidth - 23
    ctx.canvas.Height = window.innerHeight - 23
    redraw
End Sub

Public Function isClosed() As Boolean
    isClosed = window.closed
End Function

Private Sub redraw()
    'redraw shapes using ctx
End Sub

Public Sub Clear()
    ctx.clearRect 0, 0, ctx.canvas.Width, ctx.canvas.Height
End Sub
```

I commented out the line with the type mismatch so you can see that everything runs with that exception.

I tested a few different things:

- The Watch window lists the type of `document.getElementById("myCanvas")` as HTMLCanvasElement, as expected
- `?TypeName(document.getElementById("myCanvas"))` in the Immediate window returns "HTMLCanvasElement"
- `?typeof document.getElementById("myCanvas") is HTMLCanvasElement` in the Immediate window returns **False**. This is decidedly odd and makes me wonder if maybe HTMLCanvasElement is defined incorrectly in the mshtml.tlb type library.

Comment: I'm considering trying to surround the canvas with a Div and then using HTMLDivElement as a way of catching events - does anyone know how to ensure that canvas events bubble up to the surrounding Div?

Comment: Looking at the canvas in `document.all` it is of type `Variant\Object\HTMLCanvasElement`.

Comment: @ThunderFrame which is exactly why I expected it to work, but alas :(

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of cracking open the tlb to take a look for myself.  This is how it is defined:

```
    [id(0x00000440)]
    HRESULT getElementById(
                    [in] BSTR v, 
                    [out, retval] IHTMLElement** pel);
```

Note that it returns an interface pointer, not a strongly typed object. This might throw a wrench into your works, because `HTMLCanvasElement` isn't creatable:

```
[
  uuid(305106E5-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B),
  noncreatable
]
coclass HTMLCanvasElement {
```

And *nothing* in the tlb returns an instance of the coclass. This creates a problem for declaring it `WithEvents`, because the `IHTMLCanvasElement` doesn't source the events - those come from `HTMLElementEvents`.

Note that there also isn't a way to *cast* between a `IHTMLElement` and a `HTMLCanvasElement` in VBA either.  It looks like the layout of the tlb will probably limit you to either working out a `Function Declare` to try to trick the marshaller into giving you back a strongly typed object reference or working through some sort of wrapper that will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring it as an `IHTMLCanvasElement`?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975817(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `IHTMLCanvasElement` doesn't source events.

Comment: @Comintern, good point, I totally missed the events aspect. Wow, this becomes a hard problem to fix!